# Delete table rows if time in column is >07:45

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables, listobject

I'm new to VBA and have got most of what I need working but I've got stuck on this last part.

The sheet is being used to paste data into and then create a table for a specific purpose from the pasted data.

I need to write a macro that will delete the rows in a table that have a time later than 07:45 in the "Time" column.

The table is as follows:

| ID | Surname | Init | Location | Time | Event | Destination |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | Name1 | I1 | Loc1 | 18:00 | Ev1 | Dest1 |
| 34 | Name2 | I2 | Loc2 | 07:45 | Ev2 | Dest2 |
| 56 | Name3 | I3 | Loc3 | 11:00 | Ev3 | Dest3 |
| 78 | Name4 | I4 | Loc4 | 05:00 | Ev4 | Dest4 |

[This is a screenshot of the table currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5h8X.png)

After running the macro, it should look like:

| ID | Surname | Init | Location | Time | Event | Destination |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 34 | Name2 | I2 | Loc2 | 07:45 | Ev2 | Dest2 |
| 78 | Name4 | I4 | Loc4 | 05:00 | Ev4 | Dest4 |

[This is how the table should look after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXiss.png)

I've already used this code to delete empty table rows on a different file, but I'm not sure how to adapt it to work for this purpose:

```
    Dim EventsRng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set EventsRng = Range("Events[[ID]]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not EventsRng Is Nothing Then
        EventsRng.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
```

I was also suggested this, but haven't been able to adapt it to work either:

```
Private Sub deleteTableRowsBasedOnCriteria(tbl As ListObject, columnName As String, criteria As String)

    Dim x As Long, lastrow As Long, lr As ListRow
    lastrow = tbl.ListRows.Count
    For x = lastrow To 1 Step -1
        Set lr = tbl.ListRows(x)
        If Intersect(lr.Range, tbl.ListColumns(columnName).Range).Value = criteria Then
            'lr.Range.Select
            lr.Delete
        End If
    Next x

End Sub
```

```
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Events")
Call deleteTableRowsBasedOnCriteria(tbl, "Time", ">07:45")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind copying the results to another location, you can use a simple filter.

Assuming your first table is a `Table` named `Events`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteTblRows()
    Dim Tbl As ListObject
    Dim idCol As Long
    Dim Dest As Range
    
Set Tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Events")
idCol = Tbl.ListColumns("Time").Index

Tbl.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
Tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=idCol, Criteria1:="<=7:45", Operator:=xlAnd

Set Dest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(20, 1)
Dest.Resize(rowsize:=10000, columnsize:=Tbl.Range.Columns.Count).Clear

Tbl.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Dest

Tbl.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        
End Sub
```

[image]

***EDIT: to delete rows from original table***

```
Option Explicit
Sub DeleteTblRows()
    Dim Tbl As ListObject
    Dim idCol As Long
    Dim I As Long
      
Set Tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Events")
idCol = Tbl.ListColumns("Time").Index

For I = Tbl.ListRows.Count To 1 Step -1
    If Tbl.ListRows(I).Range(idCol).Value2 > CDbl(TimeSerial(7, 45, 0)) Then
        Tbl.ListRows(I).Delete
    End If
Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think the copying part of this would work, but I'll try it out, even if I just delete the rows above after. I'm looking for a foolproof, one click solution as this will be used by multiple people with varying levels of experience in Excel. Would something as simple as an IF statement work? IF value in "Time" column is >07:45 Then delete table row?

Comment: I've just tested this out and for some reason it just creates the headers, under the existing table, but there is no data under the headers?

Comment: @jwrt Added a routine to just delete table rows from original table

Comment: @jwrt Dunno why you don't see any results. I'll guess you either adapted my routine incorrectly or there is something different about your data not apparent in your example.

Comment: @ron those times aren't times, they're strings

Comment: @chrisneilsen Quite likely. If so he should change them to times.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very bodged solution, but this seems to have worked.

I’ve put a formula in a hidden column that looks at if the time in the Time column is >07:45 and if it is, it puts “DEL” in the hidden column.

```
=IF(E4>”07:45”,”DEL”,” “)
```

I then use the second macro in my original question to delete any table rows in the hidden column that contain “DEL”.

Finally, I use the first macro in my original question to delete any remaining empty cells.

Comment: This suggests (and explains why @ron 's answer didn't work for you) that your "times" aren't actually times, but string that only look like times.

Comment: I did try setting the column to time format but still had no luck, so I'm not sure what the problem was

Comment: @jwrt Changing the format does **not** change the data type. You need to execute some kind of arithmetic operation in order to do that.  eg `0+ cell_ref` or `1*cell_ref`. Ultimately, you should ensure the data is entered as times and not as text.

Comment: Ah, I see. As I say, I'm very new to this but the information has all been useful towards making it work, even if using a different method

Answer (score 0):

### Delete Excel Table (ListObject) Rows Conditionally

```vb
Sub DeleteAfter0745()
    
    Dim drg As Range
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Events").DataBodyRange
        ' Write the column values to an array.
        Dim rCount As Long: rCount = .Rows.Count
        Dim Data()
        With .Columns(.ListObject.ListColumns("Time").Index)
            If rCount = 1 Then
                ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = .Value
            Else
                Data = .Value
            End If
        End With
        ' Combine the matching rows into a range.
        Dim gtTime As Date: gtTime = TimeValue("07:45")
        Dim r As Long, drCount As Long
        For r = 1 To rCount
            If Data(r, 1) > gtTime Then
                If drg Is Nothing Then
                    Set drg = .Rows(r)
                Else
                    Set drg = Union(drg, .Rows(r))
                End If
                drCount = drCount + 1
            End If
        Next r
    End With

    ' Delete the matching rows.
    If drg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "There was nothing to delete.", vbExclamation
    Else
        drg.Delete xlShiftUp
        MsgBox drCount & " row" & IIf(drCount = 1, "", "s") & " deleted.", _
            vbInformation
    End If
    
End Sub
```